# Always open terminal window at the bottom

Tags: vim-windows

My ideal editing layout would look like this (in Gvim):

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|       |                      |                         |
|   N   |                                                |
|   E   |                      |                         |
|   R   |                Editing Area                    |
|   D   |-   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   |
|       |  (various splits, horizontal and/or vertical)  |
|   T   |                      |                         |
|   r   |                                                |
|   e   |                      |                         |
|   e   |------------------------------------------------|
|       |                                                |
|       | Terminal window (:terminal)                    |
|       |                                                |
|       |                                                |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Note in particular:

1. I want the terminal window to open at the bottom. Setting `splitbelow` might work for this, but it would affect all splits, not only the terminal window.
2. I can move the terminal to the bottom with `<C-W>J`, but this puts it below NERDTree, requiring me to then toggle NERDTree.

I'm looking to create a mapping that will allow me to open a terminal and place it where indicated in my diagram. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with:

```
:bel terminal
```

When `:bel[owright]` is followed by a command that splits a window the new window is opened below the current one. That means we first need to get to the bottom right window of the existing layout and then do `:bel`. `Ctrl-W b` is how we'd go to the bottom right in Normal mode. The Ex command equivalent is `:wincmd b`.

Combining into a mapping...

```
:nnoremap <leader>t :wincmd b \| bel terminal<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks. The following mapping is a start: `nmap <silent> <leader>s :belowright split terminal<CR>:terminal ++curwin ++close<CR><F2>` (note that I'm explicitly using nmap so that I can use my tnoremap <F2> to set the size). However, it isn't exactly what I was looking for since if I'm using vertical splits, the terminal only appears below one of the splits instead of across all but the leftmost.

Comment: I think it would be easier, in that case, to use a mapping that does `Ctrl-W J` (or equivalent) on the terminal followed by `Ctrl-W H` on NERDTree rather  than try to maneuver things around conditionally.

Comment: So you could use what I have in my answer, followed by `:wincmd J | wincmd k | wincmd H`....or something like that. (of course, you'd only do that conditionally...if there were a split on the left taking up full height). This is probably going to make more sense with a function rather than just in a mapping. Suggest you define very clearly what the "rules" are if you want that answered for y ou.

Comment: OK: Now I've got `nmap <silent> <leader>s :wincmd b<CR>\t:belowright split terminal<CR><C-W>J10<C-W>_\t:wincmd b<CR>:terminal ++curwin ++close<CR>`, which is good enough for now. (`\t` is `<leader>t`, my mapping to toggle NERDTree.) Thanks.

Comment: Oh, okay. so it's really just the NERDTree case you care about. For the heck of it I may spend a little time on a more general approach. If I come up with something I'll post it here. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

The following workflow commands can help me structure Vim windows like your desire.

1.Split below window

```
set splitbelow
```

2.Execute NERDTree

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

3.Change cursor to editor console

```
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```

4.Open terminal

```
autocmd VimEnter * terminal
```

5.Switch to terminal window

```
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd k
```

6.Increase size of main editor console

```
autocmd VimEnter * 10 wincmd +
```